# Calculating value of $\text{sinc}(x)$, WolframAlpha and MATLAB give two different answers.

Tags: trigonometry, matlab, wolfram-alpha

I need to evaluate the following:
$$\frac{2}{3}\text{sinc}\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{3}(n-4)\bigg)-\frac{1}{3}\text{sinc}\bigg(\frac{\pi}{3}(n-4)\bigg)$$

for $n=[0,...,8]$

I don't have the sinc function in my casio fx so I wanted to use the fact that $\text{sinc}(x)=\frac{\text{sin}(x)}{x}$ and that $\text{sinc}(0)=1$
Hence, for $n=0$ I got
$$\frac{2}{3}\text{sinc}\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{3}(-4)\bigg)-\frac{1}{3}\text{sinc}\bigg(\frac{\pi}{3}(-4)\bigg)=0.1378....$$

This seems to agree with wolfram alpha:

---

[image]

---

But then I checked the mark scheme on my past paper that the question is taken from, and there it says that I should've got $0.0093$ so i put it in MATLAB:

---

[image]

---

...and it also says $0.0093$.

So... which one of the two is correct? What's going on?

Comment: There is a problem for $n=4$.

Comment: Matlab includes a factor of Pi in it's definition of sinc. https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sinc.html

Comment: @JoshB. That is criminal. I need to write an angry email to Matlab.

Comment: I see. They use something called normalized sinc. And it would make senses cause Wiki says:
In digital signal processing and information theory, the normalized sinc function is commonly defined for x ≠ 0 by bla bla bla.
And the course I am doing is signal processing.

Comment: This function is not part of core Matlab but rather the Signal Processing Toolbox. As @EeveeTrainer points out below, this normalized `sinc` function is commonly used in signal processing applications that this toolbox was designed for. You can easily create a non-normalized version, e.g.: `sinc2=@(x)sinc(x/pi);`.

Comment: The normalized sinc function is convenient to use since it's $0$ at non-zero integers. Also, it happens to be the Fourier transform of the unit rectangle function, using the convention $$ \hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\Bbb R} f(x)e^{-i2\pi\xi x} f(x) dx $$

Comment: @Dudeman : "Criminal" ? Are you sure that this adjective is appropriate ? If you do a little more mathematics or physics, you will see that there are other cases in which two definitions exist for the same object up to a constant factor (which - not rarely - is a $\pi$ factor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it happens, there are apparently two different conventions for what the $\text{sinc}(x)$ function actually denotes in terms of the $\sin(x)$ function. (I ran into this same confusion on my class on Fourier analysis.) The conventions you might see are

$$\text{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \;\;\; \text{or} \;\;\; \text{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$$

The latter is known as the "normalized sinc function," per Wikipedia. I don't know much about which is used more when, so I'll leave you with the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) in that respect.

Checking your functions if interpreted in the latter way, i.e. for $n=0$

$$\frac{2}{3} \left( \frac{-3}{8\pi^2} \right) \sin \bigg(\frac{-8\pi^2}{3}\bigg)-\frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{-3}{4\pi^2} \right) \sin \bigg(\frac{-4\pi^2}{3}\bigg)$$

[Wolfram Alpha gives a value of $0.0093...$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2F3%20sin(-8%20pi%5E2%20%2F%203)%20%2F%20(-8%20pi%5E2%20%2F%203)%20-%201%2F3%20sin(-4%20pi%5E2%20%2F%203)%20%2F%20(-4%20pi%5E2%20%2F%203)), in agreement with your MATLAB answer. Indeed, as noted by Josh B. in the comments, [MATLAB uses the latter convention.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sinc.html)

I would assume, then, this is the source of the discrepancy.

Comment: Yeah I had a read about it now. Looks like I need to have a discussion with my professor. Couple of weeks ago he defines it in a "standard way" and then suddenly in the past paper it is in the "normalized way".

Answer (score 1):

[Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sinc.html)  defines
$$ \mathrm{sinc}_{\text{Matlab}} = \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t} & t \neq 0, \\
1 & t = 0
\end{cases}  \text{.}  $$

[Wolfram](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sinc.html) (in the Details section) and [the rest of the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) define
$$ \mathrm{sinc}_{\text{everyone else}} = \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin t}{t} & t \neq 0, \\
1 & t = 0
\end{cases}  \text{.}  $$

Using Matlab's nonstandard definition of this function, the value of your $n=0$ expression is $0.009321942713359250447 \dots$.

Comment: Yup. Looks like matlab is a rebel.